# How to set a default height for Grid Rows without using minHeight

Tags: wpf

I have a window in WPF, that has several Grid Rows for layout. I have a Textbox sitting inside one of the rows. I want the Textbox to have a default height, however I want the height of the textbox to increase to fit the text if necessary. I also want the Textbox to be resizable.

it seems I need to set height="Auto", but it seems like i am not able to set a default height without using minHeight, however, using minHeight would mean that the textbox is no longer resizable.

Does anyone have any ideas about it? Many thanks :)

Comment: I dont 100% understand what you want to happen.  by grid do you mean a normal layout grid?  the textbox sits inside a grid row.  you want the textbox to be a default height but be able to increase in height if the text wraps?  Could you provide code of what you have tried so we can understand more clearly?

Comment: thanks, that is exactly what I meant :) I will edit my question and add code :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment this would do what you want I think.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="20" Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="100" Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
</Grid>
```

where MinHeight="20" is your default height.  I have added a 2nd row just to take up the rest of the space.  The resizing of the TextBox is handled by the horizontal and vertical alignment properties which just force the TextBox to fill the grid row.